# need to include a new file with 'diff' utility as a patch

Tags: linux, diff, patch

When doing "diff -bBupwr" of two directories, dir and dir.orig to capture the differences, the util doesn't include files that exist only in dir, it only reports that e.g. dir/app.c exists only in dir/, but I would like it to be added in a resulting diff file, so that it could be applied as a patch.

I checked 'man diff' but no clues was found. I'd appreciate helpful advises for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the option `-N`. The man page says:

> ```
>   -N, --new-file
>           treat absent files as empty
> ```